# DRF Custom permission

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Im trying to build a custom permission in Django rest framework -

```
class GroupBasePermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    group_name = ""

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        """
        Should simply return, or raise a 403 response.
        """
        print 'self.group_name == ', self.group_name
        try:
            request.user.groups.get(name=self.group_name)    
        except Group.DoesNotExist:
            print 'group does not exist'
            msg = ('Permission denied.')
            data = {'detail': six.text_type(msg)}
            #return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

class HRAdminGroupPermission(GroupBasePermission):
    """
        Checks to see if a user is in a particular group
    """

    group_name = "HR Admin1"
```

and here is my view

```
class CompanyCreateApiView(LoginRequiredMixin,OTPRequiredMixin,GroupRequiredMixin,CreateAPIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, HRAdminGroupPermission,)
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)
    group_required = 'HR Admin1'


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        for each in self.request.user.groups.all():
            print 'self.request.user.group == ', each.name
```

When I call this API using a user(GROUP-- HR ADMIN) it does not throws me 403 forbidden error even though I see the print msg in the permission exception.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must return `True` if permission is granted, `False` otherwise in your has_permission method.

Comment: yes, it worked..Is there a way for me to notify its a 401(unauthorized) vs 403(forbidden)..True or False sets it to 403 return code.

Comment: Try " raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed() " instead of " HttpResponseForbidden " ( not tested  ).                              http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#authenticationfailed

Answer (score 3):

Something like this

```
class APIPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    message = 'Only API user can access APIs'

    group_name = "api"

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        try:
            group = request.user.groups.get(name=self.group_name)
        except Group.DoesNotExist:
            self.message = "Permission denied, user group '{}' does not exists".format(self.group_name)
            return False
        return group.name == self.group_name
```